# Unknown SQL Syntax Error near Keyword 'left'

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-update, where-clause

I am getting a syntax error "incorrect syntax near the keyword 'left'," but I don't know what I am doing wrong. I am trying to run an update query to set French addresses to 5. What am I missing?

```
UPDATE
    Persons p
    left join States s on p.StateID = p.pkState
SET
    p.International = 5
WHERE
    s.CountryRegionCodeID = 'FR';
```

Comment: The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) should always be your first port of call.

Comment: That's MySQL syntax, In MySQL the join is before the `SET`, that's why you may have seen examples around with that syntax.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct syntax in SQL Server uses a `FROM` clause:

```
UPDATE p
    SET p.International = 5
    FROM Persons p JOIN
         States s 
         ON p.StateID = p.pkState
    WHERE s.CountryRegionCodeID = 'FR';
```

Note:  I changed the `LEFT JOIN` to a `JOIN`.  The `WHERE` clause is turning the outer join into an inner join anyway.